# What's the original Korean word for an "anti-fan"?

Tags: vocabulary

The English Wikipedia has an article on [anti-fans in Korean pop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-fans_in_Korean_pop). What's the word Koreans use for an "anti-fan"?

Comment: Do you mean sth like "paparazzi"

Answer (score 3):

안티팬 or just 안티.

```
He has so many anti-fans.
```

is translated to

```
그는 안티팬이 참 많아.
그는 안티가 참 많아.
```

We use them both in everyday language.

Comment: i'm still wanting to hear a purely 한글 derived word...not something taken from another culture.  but the problem is that the koreans that are using this 외대어 are of a generation that might not know there is a pure word for this.  this is all they know.

Answer (score 1):

informal form in daily conversations: -까

e.g)
소시까 (anti-SNSD)

natives much more frequently say '-까' than '-안티' in their conversations, of course '-까' is not formal

[krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=6081400](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=6081400) / 까다 (verbal, ko-ko) 5. (속되게) 남의 결함을 들추어 비난하다.

and: [endic.naver.com/…](http://endic.naver.com/krenEntry.nhn?sLn=kr&entryId=eca75943029549ab82cc6f5a421cec06&query=%EA%B9%8C%EB%8B%A4) / 까다 (verbal, ko-en) 5. (비난하다, 욕하다) knock, run down, (Brit, inf) slate

so.. here -까 is derived from '까다', which means . Of course it is NOT recommended to use this word in formal conversations.

Comment: would you care to elaborate please?

Comment: @user17915 Look here first: http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=6081400 / 까다 (verbal, ko-ko) 5. (속되게) 남의 결함을 들추어 비난하다. // and look here: http://endic.naver.com/krenEntry.nhn?sLn=kr&entryId=eca75943029549ab82cc6f5a421cec06&query=%EA%B9%8C%EB%8B%A4 / 까다 (verbal, ko-en) 5. (비난하다, 욕하다) knock, run down, (Brit, inf) slate

Comment: so.. here -까 is derived from '까다', which means <someone who does '까다'>. Of course it is NOT recommended to use this word in formal conversations.